# How have I not won the #sql tag badge yet?

Tags: support, bug, badges, tag-badges

According to my profile on Stack Overflow:

[image]

It looks like this answer alone has earned me 220 points towards the [SQL tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql):

[SQL standard to escape column names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901453/sql-standard-to-escape-column-names/2901473#2901473)

I'm unclear why I only have credit for 84 SQL points.

It seems like this should be enough to earn the bronze SQL badge:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=Relevance&pagesize=50&q=user%3a20848%20%5bsql%5d&searchOn=3

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per the [FAQ on badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-are-the-badges-i-can-earn-on-each-site-and-what-are-the-exact-criteria-for)

> Some badges are awarded based on score. The term score means the total number of upvotes minus the total number of downvotes.

It *is* a little confusing I guess but score isn't reputation; it's based on the actual number of votes.

Comment: Ah, I missed that sentence!  Thanks for the answer.  I shall wait patiently in my cave, constantly pressing the refresh button, until I get 16 more up votes. :D

Comment: @BoltBait also, tag score only counts *non-wiki answers*. So, the correct search query is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A20848+%5Bsql%5D+is%3Aa+wiki%3A0) (which returns 20 posts as per screenshot).

Comment: While it is clearly stated on the FAQ on badges (linked in your answer), nowhere on the StackOverflow site help file is this explained and there is no link to the FAQ.

Comment: Well - this *used* to be the Stack Overflow help and covers the entire network. There's just a lot of it